# How can I insert/remove a word in the middle of a text file?

Tags: c

How can I insert or remove a word in the middle of a text file using C on Linux?

Comment: Please post the code you have written to solve this and indicate how it's not working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the whole file to a temporary location by adding/omitting the word to remove, replace the original source by the temporary file.

There's also the possiblity to use fseek() http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fseek/

Comment: You might be able to use `fseek()` to find the location - though it's a little unusual to know the byte offset to seek to - but you still have to write the replacement material to the file.  Your first paragraph is a good summary; the second is mostly immaterial.

Comment: just bear in mind that fseek will point to an offset, but if you do call a write on it, it will erase the characters starting from there (according to the length of what you're writing) it's not going to shift the content.

Comment: If I have a big file(1-2 Gb) it will take alot of space.

Comment: In case you have such large files, I think you should re-design your process. Can you give more information on the purpose of what you're doing? What is this file contain? What kind of data has to be inserted/removed? based on chat?... I can't give another answer for now.

Comment: In input I have a file(1-2Gb). File have one word in each line. I need to sort that file.

Comment: Oh god... In that case many factors come into the main picture: Memory size, Hard drive size,... If you have a lot of memory,you can still load the file into your RAM and sort it (this is the fastest way). Otherwise you can divide the file into chunks and sort each one then merge them back.

Comment: Ok. Thx a lot. I'm looking for another way.

Comment: the sipliest i see is to sort it in a second file : search for the line to be the first and write it in the new file (it will be writtenon the first line). do the same : search for the second line and put it in the second file, etc... and use an array to put the number of the lines already processed to donot process them again (or replace tose line with zeros (or another char) if you know that there is no line filled with zeros)